# text highliting Ursina in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio, ursina

I have been using vs code for about two years now and just started to get into 3d game dev in python. I installed Ursina and it works and runs fine in vs code but I am still getting these yellow warning lines. Also I have pygame installed on my computer as well if that helps.
[This is what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGJ7d.png)
can someone help?

I tried to uninstall ursina and python and reinstall them but it does not work.

Comment: here is a complete 2 hour video on Ursina:  https://youtube.com/live/uwrlDmtX2Co

Comment: i fixed it by reinstalling python but thanks. (:

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue with pygame, but here how i solved it:
1)unnistall your python-highlight extension in vscode,
2)install your python-highlight extension in vscode

(i used default python extension from microsoft)